# Birthday paradox combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Here's a problem in Harvard's *STAT 110 Probability* course:

"3. A college has 10 (non-overlapping) time slots for its courses, and blithely assigns courses to time slots randomly and independently. A student randomly chooses 3 of the courses to enroll in (for the PTP, to avoid getting fined). What is the probability that there is a conflict in the student’s schedule?"

It's similar to the Birthday Paradox. Obviously the answer is $$
P(conflict) = 1 - \frac{10}{10} \times \frac{9}{10} \times \frac{8}{10}=0.28
$$

I'm new to combinatorics and I want to get a real intuition for it, so I tried this as well: $$
P(conflict)=\frac{\binom{n+k-1}{k} - \binom{n}{k}}{\binom{n+k-1}{k}}=
0.\overline{45}
$$
Why doesn't this work? The numerator counts the number of class combinations that conflict, and the denominator counts the number of all class combinations. What am I missing?

Comment: Not following your computation.  If there are $N$ classes then the total number of possible time -assignments is $10^N$.  What are you computing?  What are your $n,k$?

Comment: If you are trying to use Stars and Bars then the problem is that your cases aren't equi-probable.  If you have three classes and two slots then the $8$ cases are $(ABC,\emptyset), (\emptyset, ABC),(AB,C),(A,BC),(AC,B), (B,AC),(BC,A),(C,AB)$  If you treat the classes as indistinguishable that means that $(3,0)$ has probability $\frac 18$ while $(2,1)$ has probability $\frac 38$.

Comment: $n$ is 10; $k$ is 3. $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ is choosing the 10 with replacement. Ahhh but order matters. $$ \frac{10^3-P(10,3)}{10^3} = 0.28$$
I'm an idiot. Should I delete this question?

Comment: No problem.  These kind of counting problems confuse everybody.  I'd leave the question up, personally, but it's your call.

Comment: You could leave the question up and answer it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the calculations that disregard order, but order matters in this question because the classes are obviously different from one another. Thus,

$$
P(conflict)=\frac{10^3-P(10,3)}{10^3}=0.28,
$$
which is the correct answer.